# Kafka Connect - NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, apache-calcite

When posting a new source connector using Confluent:

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @db2-source-conn-incr.json http://localhost:8083/connectors

I get this message:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Request failed.</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /connectors. Reason:
<pre>    Request failed.</pre></p><hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.11.v20180605</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

I have restarted my services but getting this when trying to create a new connector.

This is the log file message :

```
 [2018-10-16 14:59:09,864] WARN /connectors (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel:573)
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't properly install the DB2 Connector

Comment: The dbcc jar file was placed and confluent restarted but this was an issue with calcite driver.

Placed calcite-linq4j jar file in one of the directories under share/java and works fine now.

Comment: Feel free to put that as an answer below rather than in the comments